# Convert array to have specific keys which have prefix "suf_"

Tags: php

I have an associative array. In this array some keys have prefix "suf_". how I create a new array with these suffixed key and value? see the example below

```
Array
(
[buildings_sum] => 
[accidental_damage] => 0
[landslip_cover] => 0
[loss_of_rent] => 
[loss_period] => 
[contents_sum] => 
[suf_household_contents_sum] => 
[damage_cover] => 0
[suf_tobacco_stock_sum] => 
[stock_sum] => 
[suf_buisness_interruption] => gb
[suf_buisness_interruption_indemnity] => 24 Months
[suf_increased_cost] => vb
[suf_increased_cost_indemnity] => 24 Months
[employer_liability] => 0
[liability_sum] => 2000000
[property_owner_liability] => 1000000
[goods_sum] => hvb
[freezer_stock] => bv
[money_night_safe] => vb
[money_locked_safe] => bv
[money_not_locked_safe] => cv
[private_dwelling_money] => fcv
[suf_change_machine_money] => cfv
[suf_gaming_machine_money] => 0
[personal_accident] => cfv
[glass] => cv
[book_debts] => cv
[suf_cover_guest] => 0
[terrorism_cover] => 0
[legal_expenses_cover] => 0
[loss_of_licence] => 0
[risks_cover] => 0
[voluntary_excess] => 250
[compulsory_excess] => h
)
```

Comment: Please show some examples. What does your array look like and what should the new array look like?

Comment: I think you mean prefixes. Or do the keys look like `somethingsuf_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop and `preg_match`.  Here is a working example with youd data as an example.

```
$data_array = array();
$data_array['stock_sum'] = ''; 
$data_array['suf_buisness_interruption'] = 'gb';
$data_array['suf_buisness_interruption_indemnity'] = '24 Months';
$data_array['suf_increased_cost'] = 'vb';
$data_array['suf_increased_cost_indemnity'] = '24 Months';
$data_array['employer_liability'] = 0;
$data_array['liability_sum'] = 2000000;
$data_array['property_owner_liability'] = 1000000;
$data_array['goods_sum'] = 'hvb';
$data_array['freezer_stock'] = 'bv';
$data_array['money_night_safe'] = 'vb';
$data_array['money_locked_safe'] = 'bv';

$suf_array = array();

foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^suf_/', $key)) {
        $suf_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($suf_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and get all those elements which have the `suf_` part in the key:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 4) == 'suf_') {
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```